# Create task and subtask from a 2010 or 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, task-list

I have custom list for my license renewal process and I want to know if it's possible to create a task and subtask from a workflow. If it is, I would love to have a hint on how to get this done!

Thanks!

Seb